# sudo: command not found on ipad 9.3.5

Tags: bash, sudo, ios

i'm using ios teriminal in ipad 9.3.5. when i'm trying to use sudo command it shows command not found.

i had used **echo $PATH** and it returned

**/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games**

I was not able to find .bash_profile

can anyone tell the solution because I don't know what to do?

Comment: Are you talking about iOS 9 from like 7 years ago? And you've jailbroken it to get local shell access? Are you not already in a root shell? I would think you'd already be in a root shell and not even need to sudo. Check your jailbreak's instructions for how to get root.

Comment: I think i haven't rooted it yet, but I will try it and see whether it is working or not.